# pyspark [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hdfs://..."

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, pyspark, hdfs

I have a question about using pyspark with BeautifulSoup to parsing html files (from HDFS) to csv files and then save the csv files in HDFS.

Here is code and the error:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_path = hdfs://.../user/root/input/.../index.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(html_path))**
```

then I have the error below:

```
IOError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-875680018b76>in <module>()
----> 1 soup = BeautifulSoup(open(html_path))

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hdfs://.../user/root/input/.../index.html'
```

how to solve it?

Comment: You mean, you actually include `...` in your path??

Comment: no, that is the username and address of hdfs, cannot show here

Comment: Have a look at the HdfsCLI package https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Sorry I looked the API, and tried, but it does not work...